# How to properly apply all this image textures? Cycles

Tags: rendering, shaders

Even though I do feel like this may be a duplicate I am unsure on few on how to use them.

I downloaded a fbx from online, a free one which came with textures but I am unaware on how to use it properly.
[image]

This is what they come with and the model is this
[image]

I did something upto a point but I am unsure on how to use the two normals, the cavity, spec, and translucency. I am not even sure if I did the rest correctly.
[image]

Comment: Be sure to set everything that isn't the "color picture" to "non-color data" instead of "sRGB"  (Orange nodes). 
Translucency will either be "Alpha" or "Transmission".  Alpha = ghostly, Transmission = Glass/water like
Specular... Just wild guess, would go to the specular node. (Never seen one, so, just guessing.)
The 2nd normal would probably mix in some way with the previous normal.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This did work, still unsure where to plug the micro-normals but the results achieved from this are quite good. You can also play with the cavity color and value to give a overall color to the skin.